# 3D object rotation in WPF

Tags: wpf, 3d

I have a 3D transparent object in WPF. The opacity value for the brush used to create the object has been set to 0.25.
I have to rotate this 3D object about its central point using mouse movement.
At present, the object rotates against the direction of the mouse movement.
Does anyone have an idea on how to rotate a transparent object in 3D space?

The code used for rotation is:

```
public static void DoMouseMoveEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e, Transform3DGroup transform3DGroup, System.Windows.Controls.Viewport3D viewport3D, ref Point mLastPos, Point3D centerPoint)
    {
        var pos = Mouse.GetPosition(viewport3D);


        var actualPos = new Point(pos.X - viewport3D.ActualWidth / 2,
              viewport3D.ActualHeight / 2 - pos.Y);
        double dx = actualPos.X - mLastPos.X;
        double dy = actualPos.Y - mLastPos.Y;

        double mouseAngle = 0;

        if (dx != 0 && dy != 0)
        {
            mouseAngle = Math.Asin(Math.Abs(dy) /
                Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(dx, 2) + Math.Pow(dy, 2)));
            if (dx < 0 && dy > 0) mouseAngle += Math.PI / 2;
            else if (dx < 0 && dy < 0) mouseAngle += Math.PI;
            else if (dx > 0 && dy < 0) mouseAngle += Math.PI * 1.5;
        }
        else if (dx == 0 && dy != 0)
        {
            mouseAngle = Math.Sign(dy) > 0 ? Math.PI / 2 : Math.PI * 1.5;
        }
        else if (dx != 0 && dy == 0)
        {
            mouseAngle = Math.Sign(dx) > 0 ? 0 : Math.PI;
        }

        double axisAngle = mouseAngle + Math.PI / 2;

        var axis = new Vector3D(Math.Cos(axisAngle) * 4, Math.Sin(axisAngle) * 4, 0);

        //axis.Normalize();

        double rotation = 0.02 * Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(dx, 2) + Math.Pow(dy, 2));

        var r = new QuaternionRotation3D(new Quaternion(axis, rotation * 180 / Math.PI));

        var rotateTransform = new RotateTransform3D(r, centerPoint);            

        transform3DGroup.Children.Add(rotateTransform);

        mLastPos = actualPos;
    }
```

Could the reason of the incorrect behavior be that the z-coordinate is not captured for computing the rotation in the above code snippet?

Thanks for the help....

Answer (score 0):

i think problem in z coordinate. Becouse z coordinate using for position  in third dimension,if you dont use this coordinate rotate figure in three dimension very hard. If you calculate z coordinate i think problem will be resolved